# 653-401 Cannot rename using mv in a shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

what seem to be the problem with this code

```
#/usr/bin/ksh
RamPath=/home/RAM0
RemoteFile=Site Information_2013-07-11-00-01-56.CSV

cd $RamPath
newfile=$(echo "$RomoteFile" | tr ' ' '_')
mv  "$RemoteFile" "$newfile"
```

Error I got after running the script:

mv Site Information_2013-07-11-00-01-56.CSV
 to :653-401 Cannot rename Site Information_2013-07-11-00-01-56.CSV
             A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

The file exist on the directory. I also did putting double quotes with in variable. Same error above.

```
oldfile=$(echo "$RemoteFile" | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | sed 's/^M//')
newfile=$(echo "$RomoteFile" | tr ' ' '_')
mv  "$RemoteFile" "$newfile"
```

Comment: Add `set -u` on a line below `#/usr/bin/ksh` and run your example again.  The shell will respond with `-ksh: RomoteFile: parameter not set`

Comment: The crux of the matter is that because of the misspelled variable, the string "$newfile" is empty.  Run the script with `ksh -x script` to see how each line is executed.

Answer (score 0):

There were at least two problems:

1. The script has a typo in a variable name, as @shelter suggested.
2. The value assigned to the variable should be quoted.

**Typo**

```
newfile=$(echo "$RomoteFile" | tr ' ' '_') # returns an empty string
mv  "$RemoteFile" "$newfile"
```

The shell is a very permissive language.  Typos are easily made.

One way of catching them is to force an error on unset variables.
The `-u` option will do exactly that.  Include `set -u` at the top of your script, or run the script with `ksh -u scriptname`.

Another way to test this individually for each variable, but it adds some overhead to your code.

```
newfile=$(echo "${RomoteFile:?}" | tr ' ' '_')
mv  "${RemoteFile:?}" "${newfile:?}"
```

The `${varname:?[message]}` construct in ksh and bash will generate an error if the variable `varname` is unset or is empty.

**variable assignment**

An assignment like

```
varname=word1 long-string
```

must be written as:

```
varname="word long-string"
```

Otherwise, it will read as the assignment `varname=word` in the environment created for *command* `long-string`.

```
$ RemoteFile=Site Information_2013-07-11-00-01-56.CSV
-ksh: Information_2013-07-11-00-01-56.CSV: not found [No such file or directory]
$ RemoteFile="Site Information_2013-07-11-00-01-56.CSV"
```

As a bonus, ksh allows you to replace characters during variable expansion with the `${varname//string1/string2}` method:

```
$ newfile=${RemoteFile// /_}
$ echo "$newfile"
Site_Information_2013-07-11-00-01-56.CSV
```

---

*If you're new to (korn) shell programming, read the manual page, especially the sections on parameter expansion and variables.*

Comment: I turned this into a wiki, because there was a previous answer that mentioned the problem with the variable assignment.